# Separar os valores da List

Tags: java, lista, array

Estou usando `List` para ordenar alguns valores, mas preciso separa-los depois que manipulei os valores.

`List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> lista = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>(fila);`

E para imprimir estou usando:`System.out.println(lista);`

E assim, ele me retorna todos os elementos da lista. `[c=30, e=25, b=20]`.

A minha intenção seria como passar isso para um vetor, por exemplo, porque minha lista tem tamanho pequeno (como no caso 3). Pois se passando para um vetor, eu consigo acessar só a posição que eu quero.

Comment: Você pode acessar só a posição que você quer usando o ArrayList também, experimente fazer isso: `lista.get(0);`, ele te retornará apenas o primeiro elemento da lista. Isso já não é o suficiente para você?

Comment: me esqueci completamente do .get(). Usarei ele para usar o passar para o vetor, preciso trabalhar com vetor nessa parte. Muito obrigado @Math

Comment: Para transformar de ArrayList para vetor você pode fazer assim: `Integer vetor[] = lista.toArray(new Integer[lista.size()]);`

Comment: @Math irei usar dessa maneira que vc mesmo disse... mais uma vez obrigado! Como sempre vc me salvando... te devo cervejas, caso vc beba :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma `java.util.List` pode ser acessada diretamente pelo índice, como abaixo:

```
List<Integer> list = ...
Integer first = list.get(0);
Integer last = list.get(list.size() - 1);
```

Mas se mesmo assim ainda deseja transformá-la em um *array*, utilize:

```
Object[] array = list.toArray();
```

ou

```
Integer[] array = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

Referência e mais infortmações: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: Melhor do que isso, só isso mesmo.

Comment: Sua última linha de código me retornou o seguinte erro: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[] to Integer[]`. Tem algo errado aí, não?

Comment: É verdade!

`list.toArray()` sempre retorna um `Object[]`, para retornar um tipo definido, deve ser usado o outro método `toArray(...)`, da seguinte forma: `list.toArray(new Integer[0])`. [Documentação detalhada](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[]))

Comment: Agora funcionou :) que tal [edit] sua resposta e consertar tal informação?

Answer (score 1):

Para retornar um dado valor de uma posição da lista você pode executar o seguinte código:

System.out.println(lista.get(indice));

Penso que você não precisa passar a sua lista para um vetor pois um vetor somente "trabalha" com um tipo de dado, mas no caso você tem um MAP trabalha com o conceito de key-value, ou seja, lista possui uma chave e valor associado.

Answer (score 0):

Não use vetor, use mapas (Map) ou então implemente `hashCode` e `and equals` do objeto e trabalhe da seguinte forma.

```
List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
lista.add(new Integer(30));
lista.add(new Integer(25));
lista.add(new Integer(20));
Integer oject = new Integer(25);

int index = lista.indexOf(oject);
if (index > -1)
{
   System.out.println(lista.get(index));
}
```

No meu caso o meu objeto é Integer como você tem, mas pode fazer um objeto conforme precisar e será a mesma formula.
`lista.indexOf(oject)`, assim você pega dinamicamente qualquer posição.