# Como converter um elemento de Entry<String,Integer> para String?

Tags: java, array, string, lista

Estou usando:

```
List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> lista = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>(fila);
```

e faço algumas operações depois dessa parte.. depois que faço essas operações, preciso colocar cada "objeto" da lista em uma posição do vetor. Por exemplo na primeira posição da lista tem: `c=30` e preciso colocar em uma posição do vetor. Mas não sei qual tipo do vetor deve ser e nem como alterar, pois o `lista.get(0)` me retorna um `Entry<String,Integer>`.

A variável fila está declarada assim:

```
PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> fila = 
    new PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>(4, comp);
```

Supondo que a lista esteja assim: [c=30, e=25, b=20]
minha intenção é ter em uma string "c=30", outra string "e=25"... e por assim vai.

Comment: Poderia mostrar a declaração e inicialização da variável `fila`?

Comment: Olhando na sua outra pergunta, eu vi que seu código aqui provavelmente é a continuação daquele tópico. Lhe pergunto, não seria apenas fazer o que a resposta do mgibsonbr não lhe sugere? Assim: `Map<String,Integer> quantas = new HashMap<String,Integer>();` e `quantas.put("c", 30);`?

Comment: @Math Pelo que entendi da pergunta, a dúvida é na fase final - após todo o processo anterior (que inclui minha resposta) ter sido feito. E a resposta está na interface [`Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) - use o método `getKey()` para obter a palavra (`String`) e o método `getValue()` para obter a contagem (`Integer`). Aí você pode usar as funções de manipulação de texto (e número) que quiser...

Comment: @mgibsonbr depois de muito pensar acho que você interpretou corretamente, eu entretanto ainda não tinha conseguido entender, rs.. sinta-se a vontade para responder

Comment: [Duplicata](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33855)?

Comment: Não @GustavoCinque uma pergunta quero saber como converter para String e na outra como separar. Não poderia aproveitar uma pergunta para fazer a outra, pq foge da outra pergunta.

Comment: Beleza então. Mas tem algumas coisas que me levaram a achar que era duplicata... Na primeira questão vc não marcou resposta, como se não tivessem respondido corretamente e a duvida continuado, em uma segunda parte, há uma parte dessa pergunta ("Mas não sei qual tipo do vetor deve ser e nem como alterar... "), que define a primeira duvida que você teve. Mas sem alardes, peço desculpas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como todo objeto em Java, aqueles que implementam [`Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) possuem um método `toString`, que no caso (o `Entry` de um `HashMap`) retorna algo do tipo:

```
this.getKey().toString() + "=" + this.getValue().toString()
```

Se você quer converter esse valor para uma string diferente - sendo que não dá pra mexer na implementação do `Entry` - a solução é chamar os métodos `getKey` e `getValue` do mesmo e então formatar como quiser.

Se seu `Entry` está parametrizado para as classes `String` e `Integer`,  isso significa que a chamada desses métodos retornará objetos desses tipos (o valor podendo sofrer *autounboxing* pra `int`):

```
Map.Entry<String,Integer> meuEntry = lista.get(0);

String palavra = meuEntry.getKey();
Integer contagem = meuEntry.getValue();
int alternativa = meuEntry.getValue();
```

Aí é só uma questão de você formatar esses dados como quiser! Exemplos:

```
System.out.printf("A palavra %s apareceu %d vezes.", palavra, contagem);

String s = String.format("[%d] %s", contagem, palavra);
```

Comment: mas o meu problema que o Map.Entry está dentro de um Array. Tentando fazer como vc deu ideia, deu o erro: symbol:   method getKey()
  location: variable lista of type List<Entry<String,Integer>>

Comment: um exemplo porco, mas só pra deixar claro o que quero: String primeiro = (String)lista.get(0); Eu sei que não funciona, mas é só pra ficaar mais claro qual é a minha intenção.

Comment: Você tem certeza de que seguiu meu exemplo corretamente? Veja bem que primeiro eu faço `lista.get(0)` para retirar o primeiro `Entry` da lista, depois eu faço `meuEntry.getKey()` para retirar a `String` do entry. Seu erro sugere que você tentou fazer `lista.getKey()` - o que de fato está incorreto. Seu exemplo, em uma única linha, ficaria assim: `String primeiro = lista.get(0).getKey();`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar para adicionar usando os seguintes comandos, por exemplo:

```
//no seu caso o objeto é do tipo Map.Entry<String,Integer> 
Map.Entry<String, Integer> objeto = new Map.Entry<String, Integer>();
objeto.setValue(valorObjeto);
//no seu caso listadeObjeto pode ser a variável fila
lista.add(objeto); 
lista.add(posicao,objeto);
lista.addAll(listadeObjetos); //lista.addAll(fila);
```

Você pode alterar usando os seguintes comandos, por exemplo:

```
lista.set(posicao,objeto);
```

Você pode remover usando os seguintes comandos, por exemplo:

```
lista.remove(objeto);  
lista.remove(posicao,objeto);
lista.removeAll(listadeObjetos);
```

Comment: "Acho" que não é bem isso que o AP está precisando, mas o texto está meio confuso, então pode ser que eu tenha me enganado

Comment: `Map.Entry` é uma interface, não podendo ser instanciada diretamente (com o `new`). Entretanto, uma vez que você obtenha uma instância dela (o AP já tem várias, numa lista) o modo de manipulá-la é esse mesmo que você sugeriu (via `setValue`), mas é bom frisar que: 1) esse método é **opcional** - de modo que nem toda implementação de `Map.Entry` precisa suportá-lo; e 2) se ele existir, ele modifica **o `Map` original**, e isso só se a entrada ainda constar no `Map`. Conforme a documentação: "o comportamento dessa chamada é indefinido se o mapeamento já foi removido do map".

Comment: justamente ta meio confuso... mas pelo q eu entendi coloquei uma resposta...